# How To constraint drag and drop of grid to a panel in ext js 4 ?

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4, extjs4.1

**How To constraint drag and drop of grid to a panel in ext js 4 ?**

I am using **Ext js 4** for one of my application.

I have a **Grid on a panel** which looks something like this:

```
Ext.define('Table' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel', 
alias   : 'widget.Symbol',
title:'Table',
ddGroup : 'GridDDGroup',
hideHeaders : true,
rowLines: false,
enableDragDrop : true,  
floating:true,
columns: [/***details***/],
draggable : true,   
loadMask : true,
minHeight : 100,
minWidth : 170
});
```

I have implemented **drag and drop of the grid in the panel. DropZone** is something like given below:

```
initializeDropZone: function(g) {
                  g.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(g.getEl(), {

                      getTargetFromEvent : function(e) {
                          return e.getTarget(Ext.get('target'));
                      },

                      onNodeEnter : function(target, dd, e, data) {
                          Ext.fly(target).addCls('target-hover');
                      },

                      onNodeOut : function(target, dd, e, data) {
                          Ext.fly(target).removeCls('target-hover');
                      },

                      onNodeOver : function(target, dd, e, data) {
                          return Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropAllowed;
                      },

                      onNodeDrop : function(target, dd, e, data) {
                     //some logic
                  });
}
```

I am following MVC architecture and all the listeners are properly at it's place. And everything works fine.

Whenever I drag the grid and drop it in the same panel the logic which I have written I executed properly.

**But when I drag and drop the grid outside the panel the execution does not enter the dropzone and no method is called, hence no logic is executed. But the grid is dropped out of the panel.**

**I want to restrict the grids drag to the panel. Or else in case it is dropped anywhere outside the panel the grid should render back to the previous position.**

Can anybody help me out here?